# Matplotlib/Seaborn plot a boxplot with on the x-axis different range of values categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to make a boxplot with on the the x-axis having the x variable split in different ranges, for eg: 0-5, 5-10, 10+. Is there a way to do this efficiently in Matplotlib/Seaborn without having to create uneven new columns based on subsetting? So for this example dataset below a I want a boxplot with 3 boxes 0-5 (1a4j,1a6u,1ahc), 5-10 (1brq,1bya), 10+ (1bya,1bbs) given the *rot_bonds* variable

```
    structure rot_bonds no_atoms logP
0   1a4j    3   37  2.46
1   1a6u    4   17  1.58
2   1ahc    0   10  -0.06
3   1bbs    20  51  4.81
4   1brq    5   21  5.51
5   1bya    10  45  -9.75
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With seaborn you could use the slicing into ranges as the `x` axis, and for example `'no_atoms'` as the y-values for the boxplot:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

s = '''    structure rot_bonds no_atoms logP
0   1a4j    3   37  2.46
1   1a6u    4   17  1.58
2   1ahc    0   10  -0.06
3   1bbs    20  51  4.81
4   1brq    5   21  5.51
5   1bya    10  45  -9.75'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)
sns.boxplot(x=pd.cut(df['rot_bonds'], [0, 5, 10, 1000]), y='no_atoms', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]